# Help me get the sum of the Below given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum the series

$$2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 2 +4\cdot 3 .....(n+1)\cdot (n)$$

is there any direct formula for this?
I see each of its term in alternate fashion but don't know how to calculate this.

Comment: Do you mean $(n+1)n$?

Comment: yes that would also do.

Comment: Then it's equal to $ \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(k^2+k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2 + \sum_{k=0}^{n} k  $$

Answer (score 1):

Let our sum be $S$. Note that 
$$(k+1)^3-k^3=3(k+1)k+1.$$
Add up, $k=1$ to $n$.  There is massive cancellation (telescoping) on the left. The sum on the left is $(n+1)^3-1$.

The sum on the right is  $3S+n$. It follows that
$$S=\frac{(n+1)^3-1-n}{3}.$$
This can also be written as $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$.

**Remark:** The final expression is very attractive. The result can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom{k}{2}=\binom{n+2}{3}.$$
This result has a nice combinatorial proof, and generalizes.